# Installed the google-cloud-storage module 0.22.0, Imports fine by itself but not as an import of an import

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-python-api

I install the google cloud storage module via pip. It imports fine as a standalone.

```
>>> import google.cloud.storage
```

It imports fine if the import is in the file I'm running on. It doesn't import if I import a file from another module that's import it.

```
python dag.py list_tasks
File "/home/test/hecks/airflow-dags/dags/extract/api_extract.py", line 3, in <module>
    from google.cloud.storage import Client
ImportError: No module named cloud.storage
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate module names. Conflicted with the installed package.